# References for Counterparty Credit Risk, especially derivatives exposure

Tags: reference-request, counterparty-risk

I fortunately landed an internship in Model Risk Management in one of the largest European Banks and now am looking for good references for Counterparty Credit Risk, especially derivatives exposure, since there doesn't seem to be a lot of literature.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Giovanni Cesari, John Aquilina, Niels Charpillon, Zlatko Filipovic, Gordon Lee, Ion Manda. Modelling, Pricing, and Hedging Counterparty Credit Exposure: A Technical Guide (2009)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-04454-0)

[Eduardo Canabarro. Counterparty Credit Risk (2010)](https://riskbooks.com/counterparty-credit-risk)

[Chris Kenyon, Roland Stamm. Discounting, Libor, CVA and Funding: Interest Rate and Credit Pricing (2012)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1057/9781137268525)

[Damiano Brigo, Massimo Morini, Andrea Pallavicini. Counterparty Credit Risk, Collateral and Funding: With Pricing Cases for All Asset Classes (2013)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Counterparty+Credit+Risk%2C+Collateral+and+Funding%3A+With+Pricing+Cases+For+All+Asset+Classes-p-9780470748466)

[Roland Lichters, Roland Stamm, Donal Gallagher. Modern Derivatives Pricing and Credit Exposure Analysis: Theory and Practice of CSA and XVA Pricing, Exposure Simulation and Backtesting (2015)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1057/9781137494849)

[Ignacio Ruiz. XVA Desks - A New Era for Risk Management: Understanding, Building and Managing Counterparty, Funding and Capital Risk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1137448199) (2015)

[Jon Gregory. The xVA Challenge: Counterparty Credit Risk, Funding, Collateral, and Capital. Wiley (2015)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/The+xVA+Challenge%3A+Counterparty+Credit+Risk%2C+Funding%2C+Collateral+and+Capital%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9781119109426)

[Andrew Green. XVA: Credit, Funding and Capital Valuation Adjustments (2015)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/XVA%3A+Credit%2C+Funding+and+Capital+Valuation+Adjustments-p-9781118556788)

[Dongsheng Lu. The XVA of Financial Derivatives: CVA, DVA and FVA Explained (2015)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1057%2F9781137435842)

Answer (score 2):

Schönbucher, P., & Schubert, D. (2001). Copula-Dependent Defaults in Intensity Models. Working Paper, Bonn University.

Terentyev, S. (2004). Asymmetric counterparty relations in default modeling. Technical Report. Stanford University. ([pdf](http://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:nh293pv0521/2004-08.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend starting with this:

> [Zhu, Steven and Pykhtin, Michael (2008). ”A Guide to Modeling Counterparty Credit Risk”, *GARP Risk Review*](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1032522)

This should introduce you to all necessary concepts you might encounter in a counterparty-related internship. Then you might want to read the following:

> [Longstaff, Francis and Schwartz, Eduardo (2001). “Valuing American Options by Simulation: A Simple Least-Squares Approach”, *The Review of Financial Studies*, Vol. 14, No. 1, pp. 113-147](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~hjfurrer/teaching/LongstaffSchwartzAmericanOptionsLeastSquareMonteCarlo.pdf)

In many banks, exotic derivatives are valued using Longstaff-Schwartz techniques for the purpose of counterparty-related calculations because of its efficiency, simplicity and good performance. This might also be the case in your place.

After that, I guess additional reading is up to you and the kind of tasks you are exposed to during your internship.

Finally, considering you mention you will be working in model risk, I also recommend the following paper:

> [Derman, Emanuel (1996). “Model Risk”, *Quantitative Strategies Research Notes*, Goldman Sachs](http://pricing.online.fr/docs/model_risk.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know whether there is any textbook-like literature or is the topic too recent?

Comment: Is this related to XVA (i.e. Front Office/pricing view) or Counterparty Credit Risk (i.e. Risk view)? In XVA space, you have Gregory's _The XVA Challenge_ and Green's _XVA_ which are the standard references, though to be honest I haven't really looked at them. It really depends on what you will do in your position. For example, you might be involved in looking at fast pricers for exotic derivatives for IR products. That's not really a XVA-specific topic, and the relevant literature will probably have to be found in the pricing side.

Comment: I will most likely be in the middle office since it is part of the Risk Management.